# Do you need to commit/close a session after doing a Criteria query in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, orm, criteria

I have a code that looks like this:

```
Session session = MySessionFactory.createSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Criteria cq = session.createCriteria(clazz);
// Do stuff.
List list = cq.list();
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

Do I actually need the beginTransaction(), commit(), and close()?

I heard in JPA, CriteriaQuery (as opposed to Criteria) does not require active transaction management.

Comment: Per [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-uow), transactions are never optional. You should do all work inside a transaction and commit at the end.

Comment: Thanks. It's just confusing when I see all these examples with Criteria that do not show the session part of the code.

Comment: That's probably because that part is standard boilerplate and is implied.

Comment: @SomeNewbie: use Spring and its declarative session and transaction management, and you'll never have to open and close sessions, and to explicitely begin and end transactions.

Comment: Hah. Well, then this leads to the question of Spring vs. JBoss vs. EJB vs. Native Hibernate

Comment: @SomeNewbie if you don't close the session it may stay connected with the database. You should check available connections through database console.

Comment: @SomeNewbie: Pick any of those, but definitely use something that allows declarative transaction and session management.

Comment: @JB What's the advantage of declarative transaction aside from not having to do begin() and commit()?

Comment: That's already a huge advantage, because doing it right is not such an easy task. For example, your code above doesn't handle exceptions that could happen. Another advantage is that it makes the code much more readable, because it doesn't contain all this boilerplate code. And a third one is that it allows calling some transactional method from another, larger, transactional method.

Comment: I always like neat and packaged code, but does that add a lot of overhead? So far, the company policy is to outlaw Enterprise technology because it is too heavy weight. Admittedly, I am not too versed in the ups and downs across the different ORM systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need the session management.  However, you can do multiple operations/queries within a single transaction/session.  I would recommend starting with a single transaction per request (if you are creating a web server), job, etc. and increase the granularity of the transactions as needed.

If you want to avoid Spring then this can still be easily done with aspects however you will quickly end up repeating a lot of the work spring has done.

Answer (score 0):

*> I heard in JPA, CriteriaQuery (as opposed to Criteria) does not require active transaction management.*

That's correct.

If you change your code to standard JPA, then no query is forced to run within a transaction - provided you are SELECTING entities (and not INSERTING/UPDATING/DELETING) and are not setting a LockMode on the query.

If this was the desired JPQL:

```
SELECT c
FROM Customer c JOIN c.orders o JOIN o.lineItems i
WHERE i.product.productType = 'printer'
```

Stardard JPA Criteria Query code would be:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Customer> cq = cb.createQuery(Customer.class);
Root<Customer> customer = cq.from(Customer.class);
Join<Customer, Order> order = customer.join(Customer_.orders); // or .join("orders")
Join<Order, Item> item = order.join(Order_.lineItems);         // or .join("lineItems")

ParameterExpression<String> p = cb.parameter(String.class, "prodType");
cq.select(customer)
  .where(cb.equal(item.get(Item_.product).get(Product_.productType), p));
// if you haven't generated JPA metamodel Customer_, Product_, etc, 
// can replace this with 
//  .where(cb.equal(item.get("product").get("productType"), p));


TypedQuery<Employee> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
q.setParameter("prodType", "printer");
return q.getResultList();
```

It's a bit ugly, but it's strongly-typed (which JPQL isn't), standard, object-oriented, compiled on initialisation and hence fast.
:-)